# Java 1.4/Apache 4.1 webapplication application monitoring

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I used some good monitoring tools like javamelody and appDynamics to montior apache-tomcat 5.25 servers performance and get some useful statistics for the deployed web application (running on java 1.5 VM).

Actually I need to monitor apache-tomcat server version 4.1.24 running on java 1.4.2_12-b03 VM.
I could not find some useful tools to monitor tomcat version 4 and java 4 web applications similair to javamelody or any other +java5 monitoring tools.

Any idea abt some useful monitoring tools for apache-tomcat 4/Java 1.4?

Thanks

Comment: Could you not just upgrade? Both should be backwardscompatible

Comment: not possible it is a customer production server :)

Comment: I know such customers, but most of them fear out of support. And 1.4 is definitely end of life. ;)

Comment: yes it should be like that, but sometimes they want keep just what they have, safe side :D